# What happens at a molecular level when you cook meat?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

When we cook food how does good smell produces? and which thing converts into taste. 
Please ignore my English grammar mistakes.

Comment: "Millard reaction" (google it...) which denatures proteins. http://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/meat/INT-what-makes-flavor.html

Comment: ^ *Maillard* reaction

Comment: I also want to point out that he Maillard reaction does not denature proteins (heat does this) - it is a reaction between free amino acids and saccharides.

Comment: How do proteins denature?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. // About proteins denaturing... Think of cooking an egg. Cooking creates other "unnatural" bonds (such an egg is no longer fertile of course) in the egg which cause it to solidify.  Cooking an egg is a great example of an irreversible reaction - there is no way to uncook an egg! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaturation_%28biochemistry%29